# How to read Excel files from a stream (not a disk-backed file) in Python?

Tags: python, html, forms, request, xlrd

XLRD is installed and tested:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Sample.xls')
```

When I read the file through html form like below, I'm able to access all the values.

```
  xls_file = request.params['xls_file']
  print xls_file.filename, xls_file.type
```

I'm using Pylons module, request comes from: `from pylons import request, tmpl_context as c`

My questions:

1. Is `xls_file` read through `requst.params` an object?
2. How can I read `xls_file` and make it work with xlrd?

**Update:**

The `xls_file` is uploaded on web server, but the xlrd library expects a filename instead of an open file object, How can I make the uploaded file to work with xlrd? (Thanks to Martijn Pieters, I was being unable to formulate the question clearly.)

Comment: Should we guess what 'request' is, where 'request' comes from and which web framework you are using?

Comment: that comes from: `from pylons import request, tmpl_context as c`

Comment: It appears your problem is that you are receiving a file upload on your web server, but the xlrd library expects a filename instead of an open file object. Am I correct? If so, you may want to add that to your question. :-)

Answer (score 59):

xlrd does support providing data directly without a filepath, just use the `file_contents` argument:

```
xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=fileobj.read())
```

From the [documentation](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.open_workbook):

> **file_contents** – A string or an `mmap.mmap` object or some other behave-alike object. If `file_contents` is supplied, `filename` will not be used, except (possibly) in messages.

Comment: agree this should be the answer

Answer (score 2):

What I met is not totally the same with the question, but I think maybe it is similar and I can give some hints.

I am using django rest framework's request instead of pylons request.

If I write simple codes like following:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
def upload_files(request):
    file_obj = request.FILES['file']
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    wb = open_workbook(file_contents=file_obj.read())
    result = {"code": "0", "message": "success", "data": {}}
    return Response(status=200, data=result)
```

Here We can read using open_workbook(file_contents=file_obj.read()) as mentioned in previous comments.

But if you write code in following way:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES.get('file')
        from xlrd import open_workbook
        wb = open_workbook(file_contents=file_obj.read())
        # do some stuff with uploaded file
        return Response(status=204)
```

You must pay attention that using MultiPartParser instead of FileUploadParser, using FileUploadParser will raise some BOF error.

So I am wondering somehow it is also affected by how you write the API.

Answer (score 0):

For me this code works. Python 3

```
xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=fileobj.content)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like...

```
import xlrd

def newopen(fileobject, modes):
    return fileobject

oldopen = __builtins__.open
__builtins__.open = newopen
InputWorkBook = xlrd.open_workbook(fileobject)
__builtins__.open = oldopen
```

You may have to wrap the fileobject in StringIO if it isn't already a file handle.

Comment: Redefining `open` in `__builtins__` is *such* a bad idea.. You could at least just poke the replacement function into the xlrd module *only*..

Comment: Why? It seems a simple solution provided that you've tested it doesn't have adverse effects for the given application.