# Read-in Files from Flask request module

Tags: python, file, flask, request

I am trying to read-in a file from a Python request, form data. All I want to do is read-in the incoming file in the request body, parse the contents and return the contents as a json body. I see many examples out there like: `if 'filename' in request.files:`, however this never works for me. I know that the file does in fact live within the ImmutableMultiDict type. Here is my working code example:

```
if 'my_file.xls' in request.files:
    # do something

else:
    # return error
```

Comment: `ImmutableMultiDict([('', <FileStorage: 'my_file.xls' ('text/csv')>)])` this is what the incoming request body contains

Comment: can you add all the code needed to make your program run?

Comment: `from flask import request, Response`
`from create_app import my_app`

`import json`


`@my_app.route('/api-examples/file_parser')`
`def get_file():`
`    if 'my_file.xls' in request.files:`
`        # do something`
    
`    else:`
`        # return error`


`# main section`
`if __name__ == '__main__':`
`    my_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`

Answer (score 3):

```
if 'file' in request.files:
```

This is looking for the field name `'file'` which corresponds to the `name` attribute you set in the form:

```
  <input type='file' name='file'>
```

You then need to do something like this to assign the `FileStorage` object to the variable `mem`:

```
mem = request.files['file']
```

See [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58934639/2052575) for more details of how and why.

You can then access the filename itself with:

```
mem.filename # should give back 'my_file.xls'
```

To actually read the stream data:

```
mem.read()
```

The [official flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) have further info on this, and how to save to disk with `secure_filename()` etc.  Probably worth a read.

> All I want to do is read-in the incoming file in the request body, parse the contents and return the contents as a json body.

If you actually want to read the contents of that Excel file, then you'll need to use a library which has compatibility for this such as `xlrd`.  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418409/2052575) demonstrates how to open a workbook, passing it as a stream.  Note that they have used `fileobj` as the variable name, instead of `mem`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, please consider accepting the answer if this fixed your issue :-)